# Generate a Uniform Distribution using Names

Tags: python, random

I am attempting to generate a uniform distribution of integers between 0 and 3 in python. The program takes the user's full name as an input and then uses that to seed the PRN generator.

```py
import random

name = input('Enter your name')
random.seed(name, version=2)
value = random.randrange(0,4,1)  # should produce uniform distribution
```

The intention here is to make the PRN deterministic for each person. However, given that the letters in names are not uniformly distributed, I am not getting a uniform distribution.

Is there a better method of generating PRN's for this application?

Comment: The distribution of your seed doesn't influence the distribution of the RNG.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the distribution is not uniform? As I read your code, you are only collecting one value for each name.